# How to test for order of execution

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, testing

I've got this simple class to store and instance of the type `CurrentUser` to `Realm` called `CurrentUserStore`. There is one rule in this class, that is there can only be one record for an object at all times so for the `register(user:)` func will need to clear the Realm for that type first before adding a new user. Here's the code:

```
final class CurrentUserStore: CurrentUserStoreProtocol {
    
    private let realmAdapter: RealmAdapterInterface
    
    init(realmAdapter: RealmAdapterInterface) {        
        self.realmAdapter = realmAdapter
    }

    func initiate() throws { ... }        

    func register(user: User) {        
        if !realmAdapter.retrieve(type: User.Type).isEmpty {
            realmAdapter.clear(type: User.Type)
        }
        realmAdapter.add(user)
    }

    func retrieve() -> User { ... }

    func unregister() { ... }

}

protocol RealmAdapterInterface {
    func initiate() throws
    func add<T: Any>(_ entry: T)
    func retrieve<T: Any>(type: T.Type) -> [T]
    func clear<T: Any>(type: T.Type)
}
```

Now, to test this behaviour, I have this:

```
class CurrentUserStoreTest: XCTestCase {

    func testRegister_WhenAdapterRetrievesTooManyUsers_ShouldClearAdapterFirst() {

        let realmAdapter = MockRealmAdapter(retrieveReturnValue: [User.random(), User.random()])
        
        let store = CurrentUserStore(realmAdapter: realmAdapter)

        let inputtedUser = User.random()
        store.register(inputtedUser)
        
        XCTAssertTrue(realmAdapter.isClearCalled)
        XCTAssertTrue(realmAdapter.clearArgumentType is User.Type)
        XCTAssertTrue(realmAdapter.isAddCalled)
        XCTAssertEqual(inputtedUser, realmAdapter.addArgumentUser)

    }
}

private final class MockRealmAdapter: RealmAdapterInterface {
    private(set) var isInitiateCalled = false
    private(set) var isAddCalled = false
    private(set) var isRetrieveCalled = false
    private(set) var isClearCalled = false

    private(set) var initiateCallCount = 0
    private(set) var addArgumentUser: Any?
    private(set) var retrieveArgumentType: Any.Type?
    private(set) var clearArgumentType: Any.Type?
    
    private let retrieveReturnValue: [Any]

    init(retrieveReturnValue: [Any] = []) {
        self.retrieveReturnValue = retrieveReturnValue
    }
    
    func initiate() throws {
        isInitiateCalled = true
        initiateCallCount += 1
    }
    
    func add<T>(_ entry: T) throws {
        isAddCalled = true
        addArgumentUser = entry
    }
    
    func retrieve<T>(type: T.Type) throws -> [T] {
        isRetrieveCalled = true
        retrieveArgumentType = type
        return retrieveReturnValue
    }
    
    func clear<T>(ype: T.Type) throws {
        isClearCalled = true
        clearArgumentType = type
    }
}
```

Now, if I were to make the `register(user:)` func into this:

```
    func register(user: User) {        
        if !realmAdapter.retrieve(type: User.Type).isEmpty {
            realmAdapter.add(user)
            realmAdapter.clear(type: User.Type)
        } else {
            realmAdapter.add(user)
        }
    }
```

The test will still be green because we will still call `add(_:)` and `clear(type:)` funcs of the adapter class. Although because of the order of execution, the result will be very different. Any idea about how to test this order of execution?

Thanks.

Comment: If the order of the calls is important, you need to make your mock keep track of the order of the calls.

Comment: @matt You know what? You're right. Why didn't I think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after I've got some revelations from the comment by @matt, I've changed my mock class to this:

```
class CurrentUserStoreTest: XCTestCase {

    func testRegister_WhenAdapterRetrievesTooManyUsers_ShouldClearAdapterFirst() {

        let realmAdapter = MockRealmAdapter(retrieveReturnValue: [User.random(), User.random()])
        
        let store = CurrentUserStore(realmAdapter: realmAdapter)

        let inputtedUser = User.random()
        store.register(inputtedUser)
        
        XCTAssertTrue(realmAdapter.isClearCalled)
        XCTAssertTrue(realmAdapter.clearArgumentType is User.Type)
        XCTAssertTrue(realmAdapter.isAddCalled)
        XCTAssertEqual(inputtedUser, realmAdapter.addArgumentUser)
        XCTAssertEqual([.retrieveCalled, .clearCalled, .addCalled], realmAdapter.functionCallOrder)
    }
}

enum RealmAdapterFunctionCall {
    case initiateCalled
    case addCalled
    case retrieveCalled
    case clearCalled
}

private final class MockRealmAdapter: RealmAdapterInterface {
    private(set) var functionCallOrder: [RealmAdapterFunctionCall] = []
    private(set) var isInitiateCalled = false
    private(set) var isAddCalled = false
    private(set) var isRetrieveCalled = false
    private(set) var isClearCalled = false

    private(set) var initiateCallCount = 0
    private(set) var addArgumentUser: Any?
    private(set) var retrieveArgumentType: Any.Type?
    private(set) var clearArgumentType: Any.Type?
    
    private let retrieveReturnValue: [Any]

    init(retrieveReturnValue: [Any] = []) {
        self.retrieveReturnValue = retrieveReturnValue
    }
    
    func initiate() throws {
        isInitiateCalled = true
        functionCallOrder.append(.initiateCalled)
        initiateCallCount += 1
    }
    
    func add<T>(_ entry: T) throws {
        isAddCalled = true
        functionCallOrder.append(.addCalled)
        addArgumentUser = entry
    }
    
    func retrieve<T>(type: T.Type) throws -> [T] {
        isRetrieveCalled = true
        functionCallOrder.append(.retrieveCalled)
        retrieveArgumentType = type
        return retrieveReturnValue
    }
    
    func clear<T>(ype: T.Type) throws {
        isClearCalled = true
        functionCallOrder.append(.clearCalled)
        clearArgumentType = type
    }
}
```